# Why doesnt indexing a dataframe with only one row label work?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have created the following dataframe called states
pop area
cal 142 42
Tx  169 69
NY  114 14
Fl  117 17
Ill 114 14

I am trying various indexing options in order to understand the indexing of dataframes better.

while
'''states['pop']'''
and
'''states['cal':'ny']
and even
'''states['cal':'cal']
works
why doesnt
'''states['cal']
work?
I know there are ways to access a single row and my problem is not that I am not able to access a row of a dataframe. I just want to undestand the indexing better and know why this particular option doesnt work when
'''states['cal':'cal']'''
allows me to access a row.

Comment: I think — states['cal'] — should work just fine. Can you share the error message you're getting?

Comment: Dear Ian,The error I get is 
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

Comment: pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 'cal'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

Comment: pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 'cal'

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't read the question carefully. This code states['cal'] will only work if 'cal' is column and not a row.

Comment: Yes, thats my question. Why should 'cal' work only if its a column label and not a row label? If the answer is that indexing by 'label' only works when we use column labels then states['cal:'cal'] shouldnt work either. So I dont get why ['cal'] doesnt work but ['cal:'cal'] does.